# I'm trying to join two meshes but the textures break even when i rename the uv maps to be the same

Tags: texturing, uv

I am trying to do a simple body hack (head replacement), to do that I'd have to join two meshes (the head) and (the body) without loosing the textures, i watched a few tutorials and they mentioned just renaming the UVs on the objects you're joining the same then ctrl+j, which i did the same, but when i join them the texture still gets broken.Any idea what might be happening? And how to properly join two objects into one without loosing textures if this not the right method? I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose textures uses a default UV like this:

[image]

In this case there is only single UV can be default on the model.

So you need to replace this node by this one, there you can define that UV map you want to use:

[image]